# Function naming: sendCharacter or receiveCharacter?

Tags: function, naming

I'm trying to name a function that runs when a character is **received** by the object.

For the caller, it should be named `sendCharacter`, so that it can call:

```
object->sendCharacter( character ) ;
```

That looks nice for the caller.. but for the receiver, it implements a method

```
/// Called when this object is do something
/// with a character
/// from the caller
void sendCharacter( char c ) ;
```

So for the recipient class, it looks like this method will actually **send** a character out, not receive one.

So then, I could call the function `receiveCharacter`

```
/// Called when this object is do something
/// with a character
/// from the caller
void receiveCharacter( char c ) ;
```

But now the caller does this:

```
object->receiveCharacter( character ) ;
```

Which just looks odd.

How can I better name this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void processCharacter(char c)
 {...}`

I am glad to see someone else who agonizes over method names.  I spend too much time doing that ;)

Comment: I like the "duality" of this name - it does indeed make sense for both the caller and the recipient

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's just the example you chose, but `sendCharacter` and `receiveCharacter` are both meaningless.  *Why* are you sending a character to the object?

A better choice would be to pick something that indicates *why* the character is being sent -- for instance, `appendCharacter`.

Picking a specific "append" example: C# and Java both have a `StringBuilder` that has an `Append(string)` method.  Sure, you're *sending* the string to the instance of `StringBuilder`, and the `StringBuilder` is *receiving* the string, but that's not the point.  The point is that the string is appended to its internal buffer/array/implementation detail.

Comment: This is an interesting angle!

Answer (score 1):

If the method *reacts* on character *events*,  then how about

```
void onCharacter(char c);
```